# OWASP Zap doesn't display appropriate on Arch Linux with KDE desktop environment

Tags: kde

`````
                  .o+`                   ------------ 
             `ooo/                   OS: Arch Linux x86_64 
            `+oooo:                  Host: XPS 17 9700 
           `+oooooo:                 Kernel: 6.3.7-arch1-1 
           -+oooooo+:                Uptime: 16 mins 
         `/:-:++oooo+:               Packages: 1328 (pacman) 
        `/++++/+++++++:              Shell: zsh 5.9 
       `/++++++++++++++:             Resolution: 3840x2400 
      `/+++ooooooooooooo/`           DE: Plasma 5.27.5 
     ./ooosssso++osssssso+`          WM: kwin 
    .oossssso-````/ossssss+`         Theme: [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
   -osssssso.      :ssssssso.        Icons: [Plasma], breeze [GTK2/3] 
  :osssssss/        osssso+++.       Terminal: konsole 
 /ossssssss/        +ssssooo/-       Terminal Font: Hack 14 
`/ossssso+/:-        -:/+osssso+-     CPU: Intel i7-10875H (16) @ 5.100GHz 
`+sso+:-`                 `.-/+oso:    GPU: Intel CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] 
`++:.                           `-/+/   GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 Max-Q 
.`                                 `/   Memory: 4746MiB / 31718MiB
`````

Zap shows a super tiny windows on the system. Changing to `"Display Configuration" -> "Legacy Applications (X11)" -> "Scaled by the system"` can fix the problem, but all other windows are blur.

Answer (score 0):

```
export GDK_SCALE=2
```

Using above command set the environment variable temporarily or add this command to your shell profile to persist the change to getting an appropriate window of Zap without changing the global scaling settings.

Another option is:

```
env GDK_SCALE=2 zaproxy
```

Reference: [HiDPI ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/HiDPI#GDK_3_(GTK_3))